# Macro with Save Current date

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to make a macro to save a file with the current day in the name. I want to save this off everyday with the correct date.

This is what I have as a macro, pretty simple, but I am having issues with getting the current date formula in the file name (if possible)

```
Sub Save()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="X:\file06-21-2012\.xlsm", FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

So tomorrow i would want the marco to save it as file06-22-2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub Save()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NewName As String

    FilePath = "X:\": NewName = FilePath & "file" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 we think alike on this! I think everyone posted at the same time!

Comment: I get Compile Error Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment and Format is highlighted?

Comment: @AdamG.: Did you copy the code exactly like it is given above?

Comment: @AdamG.: The reason why I ask is because, I have tested the above code and it works :)

Comment: yes it look like I copied it exactly but still getting the error

Comment: @AdamG.: A Shot in the dark Try this... Add `VBA.` before `Format` so it becomes `VBA.Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY")` Now try it

Comment: That worked. Thank You. What does adding that do? Sorry for so many dumb questions

Comment: @AdamG.: No it is not a dumb question :) I have seen this problem before where VBA refuses to recognize commands like `TRIM`, `FORMAT` etc. I think I know why that happens but I am not sure if what I know is correct. Let me do some research on it before I confirm it to you :)

Comment: @AdamG.: Ok Check this for me. Open Menu: Tools--> References. Check if there are any Missing libraries

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  I understand that this is for Excel, but wouldn't this have to be in hard coded into one's Excel? Is it possible to hard code this for every file on one's computer running windows?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife: `Is it possible to hard code this for every file on one's computer running windows` No it is not possible BTW when you say any file i am assuming all kinds of extensions

Answer (score 3):

WIth all due respect to @HeadofCatering's answer, a simpler, more easily readable approach would be this, I think.

```
Sub Save()

Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = Date

Dim strFile As String
strFile = "X:\file" & Format(dtDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for getting it at the same time ;) BTW, you might want to remove the extra variables like dtDate and make your code shorter :)

Comment: good point. It's kind of habit a bit though, for when I want to be able to change a variable once... but of course, this doesn't apply to this small block.