# VB Save to current path and filename, plus add current date to filename

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am very, very new to VB and am grateful to have found this site!

I searched and reviewed every auto-suggested similar Q&A links for my question but didn't find exactly what I was looking for (perhaps because I didn't understand what I was looking at... ;-).

I used this Excel macro from another user's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145421/macro-with-save-current-date), answered by [Siddharth Rout:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)

[Macro with Save Current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145421/macro-with-save-current-date)

```
Sub Save()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NewName As String

    FilePath = "X:\": NewName = FilePath & "file" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

This works perfectly if I want the file to be named "file" (or whatever I insert in the quotes).

But, how would I edit this macro so that it would work on any open file so that the current date is added to the file's existing path and filename?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Andy

Answer (score 3):

```
dim last_dot as long
last_dot = InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")

dim NewName as string
NewName = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, last_dot - 1) & Format$(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & Mid$(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, last_dot)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Can you dumb it down further for me please? :-)  Where do I insert your script and what does it replace in mine?  Thanks!

Comment: It replaces code between `Sub Save()` and `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`, non-inclusively.

Comment: Thank you again - received a run-time error '1004':  "This extension can not be used with the selected file type.  Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type."  I took a complete noob shot in the dark and deleted the FileFormat portion.  That worked, but I don't know why.  If you have time to explain, I'd be grateful - regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: @AMM `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` requests the xlsm format whereas you want to keep your current format. You do that by not providing a parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much - that makes sense.  I have a curveball for you if you're interested:  Could this be modified further to add a version number (e.g., "v1") if saving the same file many times on the same day?